# Curl to get Rabbitmq queue size

Tags: curl, rabbitmq

Is there a way to get the size (remaining messages) of a queue in rabbitmq with a simple Curl?

Something like `curl -xget http://host:1234/api/queue/test/stats`

Thank you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally I did the trick with the following:

```
curl -s -i -u guest:guest http://host:port/api/queues/vhost/queue_name | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep '"messages"' | sed 's/"messages"://g'
```

Comment: Anything which looks like `sed | grep | sed` should probably be refactored.  I would go for `curl ... | sed -n 's/.*"messages:" *\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'` but YMMV.  If the output is proper JSON, `... | jq -r .messages` is simpler and more readable. (Not in a place where I can test.)

Comment: Also the `curl -i` option appears to be rather useless if you are throwing away the headers anyway.  I was tripped by the requrement to percent-code the vhost parameter; `curl -s -u guest:guest http://localhost:55672/api/queues/%2F/queuename | grep -o '"messages":[0-9]*'` works for me.

Answer (score 11):

As much as I love hacky sed one-liners this is probably the cleanest solution:

```
curl -s -u <user>:<password> http://<host>:<port>/api/queues/<virtual-host>/<queue> | jq .messages
```

Comment: If you just happen to be using the default vhost of "/" use the encoded version of "/", which is "%2F".

Answer (score 6):

Use HTTP API from [Management Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#http-api-endpoints).

It looks you may benefit from `/api/queues/(vhost)/(name)` one. The output is in plain json, so you won't miss `messages` field (and related).

Comment: the  http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/86f7d33a6284/priv/www/doc/stats.html is broken

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate this is an old post & that the question specifically states using "curl" but thought it might be useful to add that the "rabbitmqctl list_queues" command provides the message count for each queue

Answer (score 0):

`curl -u login:password http://localhost:15672/api/queues | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep '"messages"\:'`

Rabbitmq v3.3.4 PHP library based on HTTP api.

[REQRequest](https://github.com/Sahil-Gulati/REQRequest)