# How to scale up the queue in RabbitMQ dynamically?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

can I create queue dynamically using RabbitMQ?

In my application, I want the queues to scale up dynamically whenever the queue is full.can I do that with RabbitMQ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a dynamic queue but you can create a fixed size one, then monitorize it and scale up when it is getting full.

You can change the size at runtime via a policy in the RabbitMQ server through the management plugin's HTTP API.

Here it is a example of how to change the queue size parameter: https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html.

And here how you can change it at runtime via a policy: https://www.rabbitmq.com/parameters.html.

The monitoring task is also done via management plugin's HTTP API. Here some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24408669/8041414

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for your response.In my application, whenever the message queue is full it should create another queue.                                                                      Is there any way to dynamically to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is also possible through the management plugin's HTTP AP. There is a method to create antoher queue and binding it to your consumer

Comment: Thanks.how to find the queue is full or not,  programmatically through the code and dynamically create another queue without management plugin?. is there any sample available?

Comment: I set a queue length limit and if exceeds the limit, I forwarded that messages to another queue programmatically.